# OpenSSH on Windows always binds sockets used for Remote Forwarding to LOOPBACK

Tags: windows, ssh, ssh-tunnel

Like the title says.

Host A acts as a server (bastion-host, call it whatever you will).

Now, host B performs:

> ssh -R 2222:localhost:22 user@A

as a result a TCP socket gets spawned at A, but it is bound to 2222@**Loopback** i.e. preventing remote connections to it.

How to change 127.0.0.1 to 0.0.0.0 **or anything else** more sensible?

Comment: Think I Got it: GatewayPorts set to yes in SSH config.

Answer (score 2):

You're missing the optional `bind_address` part of the `-R` specification. In the [`ssh` documentation](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh) (as linked by [Microsoft](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/openssh/openssh_install_firstuse)) it writes,

> By default, TCP listening sockets on the server will be bound to the loopback interface only. This may be overridden by specifying a `bind_address`.  An empty `bind_address`, or the address `*`, indicates that the remote socket should listen on all interfaces. Specifying a remote `bind_address` will only succeed if the server's `GatewayPorts` option is enabled (see [sshd_config(5)](https://man.openbsd.org/sshd_config)).

You're using the three-tuple version of the parameter, but you need the four-tuple version:

> ```
> -R port:host:hostport
> -R [bind_address]:port:host:hostport
> ```

So, to allow anyone to connect to the listening port on the remote server, you need to ensure that `GatewayPorts` is enabled in the server's `sshd_config` *and* use a command variation like this:

```
ssh -R :2222:localhost:22 user@A
```

The leading colon (`:`) also implies a leading asterisk wildcard that allows connections from anywhere. Personally I think this version with the wildcard makes it clearer that what is written is intentional:

```
ssh -R *:2222:localhost:22 user@A
```